# Need help with mathematical induction

Tags: induction

> Suppose $a, b$ are positive real numbers. Then $\frac{a^n + b^n}{2} \ge \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^n$ for any $n$ ∈ $\mathbb{N}$ \ {$0$}.

How should I prove the above statement by mathematical induction? I am stuck in the step in proving $P(k+1)$.

Comment: How far did you get in the inductive $P(k+1)$ step?

Comment: Its a good way to start with the right-hand side and evaluate it.

Comment: @Arthur I tried to start from the RHS but I'm not sure how to continue... I tried to multiply (a+b)/2 to both sides of P(k).

Answer (score 1):

By the induction hypothesis,
$$
\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{\!k+1}=\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{\!k}\frac{a+b}{2}\le\frac{a^k+b^k}{2}\frac{a+b}{2}
$$
Can you compare the last term to
$$
\frac{a^{k+1}+b^{k+1}}{2}
$$
and finish the task?